# The need for quotes in templates?

Tags: angular, angular-template

*(Yet another naive question from a refugee from the Flex/Actionscript world...)*

I am confused about whether or not I need to use quotes in my component template. In the snippets below there are two `@Inputs` and one `@Output`. Both work, with the first snippet using quotes for the component property references and the second one not.

I don't like doing things "just because I saw it in a tutorial".
Is there a reason to use quotes or not?

---

```
   <app-pov-button *ngFor="let event of eventList" 
         [assetPath] = 'assetPath'
         [eventData]= 'event' 
         (eventClicked)= 'onEventClicked($event)'
         >
  </app-pov-button>
```

---

```
  <app-pov-button *ngFor="let event of eventList" 
     [assetPath] = assetPath
     [eventData]= event 
     (eventClicked)= onEventClicked($event)
     >
  </app-pov-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property value contains space(s) (and probably a few other characters) quotes are required. For consistency they are usually used everywhere.

See also this discussio https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7295